# Twig translate whole text of rendered view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Using Twig I render a particular view. I need this view to be translated into a language I choose. I display the view using:

```
return $this->setup->twig->display($view, $params);
```

Where `$view` is the name of the `*.html.twig` template and `$params` is an array with the parameters I need to pass.

However, if I want to translate the template before displaying it, how I have to do it?

Currently I have included .yml files for different languages and I have also replaced the text inside the views with the appropriate corresponding values from the yml file.

Apart from everything else, I have also loaded the Twig translator in a file separate from the rest of the project. It has the following code:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader;

class Translation
{
    public $translator;

    public function translator()
    {
        $this->translator = new Translator('fr_FR');
        $this->translator->addLoader('array', new ArrayLoader());
        $this->translator->addResource('array', array(
            'Symfony is great!' => 'J\'aime Symfony!',
        ), 'fr_FR');

        var_dump($this->translator->trans('Symfony is great!'));
    }
}

$show = new Translation;
$show->translator();
```

And it really displays the translation.

Still, I have no idea how to connect everything together....

Comment: Have a look to http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Comment: Symfony already has that you needs, just use it, look at link above into "Translations in Templates" section.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the locale before rendering your twig view?

```
public function exampleAction(Request $request) {
    $locale = 'de'; // Set the language
    $request->setLocale($locale);

    $content = $this->renderView($view, $params);

    // Maybe return to default locale....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the idea behind this code solved a lot of my problems. The only problem I face now is that when, after I change the locale language, I try to render a view, it is not translated. However, if I use the trans() function with a string, for example var_dump($this->translator->trans('Symfony is great!')); Then, it is translated

Comment: Can you show me your template? Do you use trans or transchoice in your template to get your message translated? Ex: {{ 'dummy.text'|trans }}

Comment: I made a test template, in it I have only {% trans %}great{% endtrans %} and in my messages.it.yml file I have great:  "Supremo"

Comment: Before rendering the template I use $this->translator = new Translator( 'en_EN', new MessageSelector() ); $this->translator->addLoader( 'yaml', new YamlFileLoader() ); $this->translator->addResource( 'yaml', dirname ( __DIR__ ) . '/Resources/Vrs/Translations/messages.it.yml', 'it_IT' ); $this->translator->setLocale( 'it_IT' ); return $this->setup->twig->display( $view );